# How to change value of a variable when button is pressed tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to detect a button press in tkinker but every method on google does not work for me, i want to change variable value for my python project.

Here's the basic code:

```
from tkinter import *

win= Tk()
win.geometry("500x600")

up = Button(win, text="⬆", bg="yellow", borderless=1, width=150, height=100, command = var = 1)
up.place(x=0, y = 500)

win.mainloop()
```

How do i do that?

Comment: The `command=` option has to name a *function*.  That function can do whatever it wants, including assigning values to variables.

Answer (score 0):

Sourced from: [To Detect Button Press In Python Tkinter Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61639278/to-detect-button-press-in-python-tkinter-module)

You could just place the variable change within a function

```
up = Button(win, text="⬆", bg="yellow", borderless=1, width=150, height=100, command=changeVar())

def changeVar():
    var = 1
```

Or something close to this, assuming it's in the global namespace, since you're attemping to change it via var = 1 anyway.

Comment: Putting a `return` value in a Button's `command=` function is utterly pointless.  Nothing is ever going to see that value.