# if statements, TTK

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

```
ytac=[]

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self, title: str):
    super().__init__()
    self.title(title)

    self.style = ttk.Style(self)
    self.style.theme_use("classic") 

    self.frame0 = ttk.Frame(self, padding=(5,5))
    self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self, padding=(5,5))
    self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self, padding=(5,5))
    self.frame3 = ttk.Frame(self, padding=(5,5))

    self.initialize_frames()
    self.initialize_widgets()
    self.geometry("450x400")
  

    
  def initialize_widgets(self):
    self.uno_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=10)
    
  def make_frame0(self):
    self.coding_button = ttk.Button(self.frame0, text="Coding", command=self.get)
    self.coding_button.grid(row=1, column=5)

  def make_frame1(self):
    self.gamedev_button = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="Game Development", command=self.get)
    self.gamedev_button.grid(row=1 ,column=5)

  def make_frame2(self):
    self.digitalmedia_button = ttk.Button(self.frame2, text="Digital Media", command=self.get)
    self.digitalmedia_button.grid(row=1, column=5)

  def make_frame3(self):
    self.uno_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Hello fellow Ytacer or so they call 'it. Ytac is a 4 week journey that allows to \ntake a Stem class of your choosing from a not so wide range of classes. \nIt's also unfourtenetly not sponsored by Dr.Pepper(f in the chat). 'Are you ready \nto start your expedition? What's 'my name you 'ask? I have 'no name but you \ncan call me Took. 'And also, Mel 'sucks and 'shouldn't be 'appreciated \nthroughout the rest of the cohort. *ahem*, they're 3 pathways to choose from,\n Coding(1), Game Development(2), Digital Media(3). Choose from one of these \nby clicking on the respective button. But before you do that I would like for us \nto introduce our sponsors RAID SHADOW LEGE-.") 
  

    
  def initialize_frames(self):
    self.make_frame0()
    self.make_frame1()
    self.make_frame2()
    self.make_frame3()

    self.frame0.grid(row=4, column=0)
    self.frame1.grid(row=4, column=1)
    self.frame2.grid(row=4, column=2)

  def get(self):
     if self.coding_button:
       print("ok")
     elif self.gamedev_button:
       print("poyo") 
     elif self.digitalmedia_button:
       print("GUH-HUH")
      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App("YTAC")
    app.mainloop()
```

This def function will only print out the first string and not the other two even though I pressed all corresponding buttons.
[image: Reference]

Expected corresponding string to print out after I pressed the corresponding button. I tried to change the elifs to their own if statements but that caused more problems.

Comment: hint: `if self.coding_button` is going to always be true as long as `self.coding_button` is set to some non-False. If it is a button, it will always be true.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all of the code I cannot accurately diagnose your problem, but it may lie in how you're using the Tkinter buttons.

Another question that seems similar to yours
[To Detect Button Press In Python Tkinter Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61639278/to-detect-button-press-in-python-tkinter-module)

A very thorough tutorial for Tkinter buttons:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm

Essentially, Tkinter buttons are defined like so:

```
buttonName = tkinter.Button(master, option1=value1, option2=value1...)
```

Tkinter buttons have no "is pressed" variable, instead, you set the command (a function) that runs when the button is pressed.

```
buttonName = tkinter.Button(master, command=function_name, option1=value1, option2=value2...)
```

***Note: Don't put parentheses after the function name as that will run the function. The only exception is if you have a function that returns a function***

If you want a global variable that's changed when you push the button, a function like so works:

```
global_var = False
def callback():
    global global_var
    global_var = not global_var
button = tkinter.Button(master, command=callback)
```

In the above example, replace `master` with the name of the Tkinter window.